# Firebase deploy to hosting fails with Error: Failed to fetch Run service projects/

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-run, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to set up a static site on Firebase Hosting to call out to Cloud Run by following the steps here:
[Serve dynamic content and host microservices with Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run)

I've deployed the container image and have a containerized app running. I confirmed this by visiting the deployed container by opening the service URL in a web browser.

I can also see the Cloud Run service:

```
$ gcloud run services list
   SERVICE        REGION       URL                                            LAST DEPLOYED BY   LAST DEPLOYED AT
✔  paths-backend  us-central1  https://paths-backend-...
```

and the Firebase project:

```
$ firebase projects:list
- Preparing the list of your Firebase projects
✔ Preparing the list of your Firebase projects
┌──────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ Project Display Name │ Project ID            │ Project Number │ Resource Location ID │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ Paths                │ paths-e9ce1 (current) │ ...
└──────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────────┘

1 project(s) total.
```

When I run `firebase deploy --only hosting` with the following firebase.json, it works:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However when I try to follow the last step on the page and set the rewrite for my containerized app, it fails:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "run": {
        "serviceId": "paths-backend",  // "service name" (from when you deployed the container image)
        "region": "us-central1",    // optional (if omitted, default is us-central1)
        "pinTag": true              // optional (see note below)
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

```
$ firebase deploy --only hosting

=== Deploying to 'paths-e9ce1'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting: The site paths-e9ce1 will pin rewrites to the current latest revision of service(s) paths-backend
i  hosting[paths-e9ce1]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[paths-e9ce1]: found 15 files in build
✔  hosting[paths-e9ce1]: file upload complete
i  hosting[paths-e9ce1]: finalizing version...

Error: Failed to fetch Run service projects/paths-e9ce1/locations/us-central1/services/paths-backend
```

Any ideas how to get this to work, or debug it further?

Comment: Whenever you are using Firebase Tools with a version that is less than or equal to v11.18.0, you might encounter the error. You may fix this issue by updating the version of firebase-tools using the command `npm install -g firebase-tools`. And the latest version of firebase tools is [12.4.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is with 12.4.4 though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had set up Firebase Hosting with a different project than the one I used for Cloud Run.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).